# Isotope: keep an element in the first row, last column of the grid

Tags: locking, jquery-isotope

Using Isotope, I would like to know how to keep an element always in the first row, last column of the grid, no matter how many columns there may be.

Not the corner stamp function since it makes the element appear outside of the grid, unaligned with the other elements.